# If $G$ is a finitely presented group then is the commutator of $G$ isomorphic to the commutator of $F$ mod the relations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Let $G=\langle\ S\ |\ R\ \rangle$ be a finitely presented group. Let $F$ be the free group with generating set $S$. Let $[F,F]$ and $[G,G]$ be the commutator subgroups of $F$ and $G$ respectively. Let $N$ be the normal subgroup of $F$ generated by $R$.

> **Is it true that $\dfrac{[F,F]}{N\cap[F,F]}=[G,G]$ ?**

If $\pi:F\to F/N=G$ is the cannonical map then clearly $\dfrac{[F,F]}{N\cap[F,F]}=\pi([F,F])$ and is a normal subgroup of $G$. To show $[G,G]\subseteq \dfrac{[F,F]}{N\cap[F,F]}$ it is enough to show $G$ mod $\dfrac{[F,F]}{N\cap[F,F]}$ is abelian. But I am unable to do so. Also I have no idea how to show the reverse containment. Is there a counter example for the statement?

Thank you.

Comment: $[G,G] = [F,F]N/N \cong [F,F]/(N \cap [F,F])$.

Comment: It is easy to show $[G,G]\subseteq \dfrac{[F,F]}{N\cap[F,F]}=\pi([F,F]).$ Just recall the definition of $[G,G]$ as $\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\}$ and that $F$ has a surjection to $G.$ The other direction is even simpler: $$\pi([F,F])=[\pi(F),\pi(F)]\subseteq[G,G].$$

Comment: $\pi$ induces an abelian group homomorphism $[F,F] \to [G,G]$, so you merely need to show this induced homomorphism is onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple explanation:
$$\begin{align}\pi([F,F])&=\pi(\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}:x,y\in F\})\\
&=\{\pi(x)\pi(y)\pi(x)^{-1}\pi(y)^{-1}:x,y\in F\}\\
&=[\pi(F),\pi(F)]\\
&=[G,G]\end{align}$$

Hope this helps.